# Python3 Unittest Mocking Requests Module

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I am comfortable using dependancy injection with Java's Mockito library, but have little experience using Python3's `unittest.mock` module. I am trying to assert that the `Request` instance's `prepare` method gets called. However the test fails on the assertion `self.assertTrue(mock_request.prepare.called)`. Can someone please advise me on how to get this test passing?

```
import requests

import unittest
from unittest import mock

class Engine(object):

    def get(self, **kwargs):

        session = requests.Session()
        req = requests.Request('GET', 'http://www.google.com', params=kwargs).prepare()
        response = session.send(req, timeout=1)


class TestEngine(unittest.TestCase):

    @mock.patch('requests.Session')
    @mock.patch('requests.Request')
    def test_get(self, mock_request, mock_session):

        e = Engine()
        e.get()

        self.assertTrue(mock_request.called)
        self.assertTrue(mock_request.prepare.called)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code never accesses `prepare` on `Request` directly. The method is accessed on the *return value* of a call to `Request()`, so test for that instead by using the [`Mock.return_value` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value):

```
self.assertTrue(mock_request.return_value.prepare.called)
```

When debugging mock issues, I find it helpful to print out the [`Mock.mock_calls` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.mock_calls) for the top-level mock object; for your test printing `mock_request.mock_calls` produces:

```
[call('GET', 'http://www.google.com', params={}), call().prepare()]
```

showing that `call().prepare()` was indeed accessed (and the result of a `call()` is usually accessible via the `Mock.return_value` attribute, as shown above).